# Asp.net Core MVC - IdentityUser Is Not Getting Deleted

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an asp.net core mvc project and I am using ef-core with IdentityUser. I encountered an error while deleting the user. Previously the delete code was working fine. After I applied the javascript confirm box to confirm the delete operation, the confirm box appears but when I click on **OK**, it doesn't delete the user anyhow.I tried to remove the javascript code, but it still doesn't delete the user anyhow. Please do help.

Here is the code for the submit button and form tag :

```
<form method="post" asp-route-Id="@user.Id" asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-controller="Admin">
                                        <button type="submit" onclick="return DeleteU()" class="btn btn-danger w-100">
                                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
    function DeleteU() {
        var result = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete The User?")
        if (result) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the code of controller method :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(string Id)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                _db.Users.Remove(user);
                await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("UserMgmt");
            }

        }
```

Comment: You could debug your Controller Action and see why it isn't deleting.

Comment: I put a debug point on the controller method and to my surprise.. code doesn't even reach there.. when I press the delete button.. it just refreshes the page..

Comment: P.S. : to my surprise.. if I try to add another user and try to delete it... it works.(without js code) but.. the previous one which i was trying to.. is not getting deleted.

Comment: You tell us if you create a new user, and delete it, it works well, right ? So please create a new one and compare the difference between this user and the new one.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly you have to delete it using UserManager and it will automatically reflect in database
> `public async Task DeleteUser(string Id)
> {
> var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);

```
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()
            await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            await transaction.CommitAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("UserMgmt");
        }

    }.
```

Comment: Tried it.. but not working out.. :(